# Get apple nutrition data using HKStatisticsCollectionQuery from other sources as well

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am trying to get apple nutrition data using HKStatisticsCollectionQuery from all sources

```
NSCalendar *calendar       = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
interval.day               = 1;

NSDateComponents *anchorComponents =
[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth |
 NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

anchorComponents.day -= 30;

NSDate *anchorDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:anchorComponents];

HKQuantityType *quantityType =
[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCalcium];

NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:anchorDate endDate:[NSDate date] options:HKQueryOptionNone];

// Create the query
HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query =
[[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc]
 initWithQuantityType:quantityType
 quantitySamplePredicate:predicate
 options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum
 anchorDate:anchorDate
 intervalComponents:interval];

// Set the results handler
query.initialResultsHandler =
^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: %@ ***",
              error.localizedDescription);
        abort();
    }

    self.statisticsCollectionResults = results;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.statisticsCollectionResults.sources);

};

[self.healthStore executeQuery:query];`
```

By using this code, I am getting nutrition data only for my app. But I need nutrition values entered from other sources as well.

Comment: Are you sure your app has been given read authorization for the data type you want to query?